# How to automatically extract all the source code and header files that a small project depends on, within a big project?

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, include, gnu-make

A small project is in a big project. The small project that can be compiled with `make` only uses a small part of the files of this big project. Are there any tools that can automatically extract all the source code and header files that this small project depends on? Manually picking is definitely feasible, but it is inefficient and error-prone since the `Makefile`s are complex and deeply-nested. Modern IDEs usually build indexes, and I don't know if any IDEs provide this feature of extracting all dependencies.

I ended up using the `Process Monitor` tool to track and filter all the `OpenFile` system calls of the build system on Windows, then exported the report and wrote a script to copy the files. But such an approach is not so elegant >_<

Comment: Can your current makefile system build the small project? When it does so, does it compile only the necessary sources? Does it print the commands it's issuing to the compiler?

Comment: Yes, but the outputs are long since they include many directories of header files, but not all of them are used. One can write scripts to analyze these outputs, but such scripts may only be specific to this project and not universal.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer a question like this, with so many hidden variables. I can think of a few other ugly twists that could be hiding in this build system, which would defeat the simple approach, but *if you have such a perverse build system then you must deal with it.* What happens when you pipe the output through a simple sed script that retains only the names/paths of source files? If you get a list of those, then a simple makefile might suffice to generate a list of necessary header files.